# Checking for c library

Tags: bash

What is the best method in bash to check to se if a c library is installed?

**Per comments, to be more clear:**
I run an install script that looks for the libexpat header file (expat.h)
Currently it is doing this via:

```
if ! locate libexpat.so 1> /dev/null; then
```

However, it should be looking for expat.h, but this still required the mlocate db to be updated first.

Any better way?

Comment: `whereis -b libc` ? `find / -name libc` ?

Comment: @cnicutar, never seen `whereis -b` before :) Neat. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best one I found was with @cnicutar's comment, thanks.
Specifically to do this in a bash script:

```
expat_loc=`whereis -b expat.h | cut -c8-`
if [[ -e "$expat_loc" ]]; then
  #Something something
fi;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do as `autoconf` does (or, more accurately, `configure` scripts generated by `autoconf` do), and test whether you can compile a C program that uses the library.

If you don't have a compiler or the development tools installed, your options are more limited.

It also isn't clear whether you want to search in out of the way locations for the library, or if you are only concerned with it being installed in the main library directories.  Also, are you looking only for shared libraries, or are you looking for static libraries - the naming conventions differ wildly depending on what you're up to, and which machine type you are doing it on (Linux and Solaris vs AIX vs MacOS X vs HP-UX (older, for PA-RISC) vs Windows, for instance).  If you're looking for static libraries, you'll be hard-pressed to use them without the compiler (and probably the headers).  If you're looking for shared libraries, you can use those without the development paraphernalia if you compile the program on some other machine and copy it to the target machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you need runtime, you'll need a specific version for running some stuff. Try to run that stuff.
If you need headers, try to compile something.